# Pseudocódigo en c

Tags: array, c, pseudocódigo

quisiera saber si está correcto lo que hice, estoy aprendiendo **pseudocódigo en C** y estoy haciendo ejercicios, me ayudaría mucho si pudieran corregir mis errores o darme recomendaciones. En este ejercicio debo sumar los elementos de un arreglo A en n posiciones, mi pseudocódigo es el siguiente:

```
declaro numeros = 1,2,54,28

longitud = tamañoNumeros / tamañoNumeros[0]

sumatoria = 0

for i = 0; i < tamaño; i++

    numeroActual = numeros[i]
    sumatoria = sumatoria + numeroActual

return(sumatoria)
```

Comment: y... que es tamaño?? porque no esta definido...

Comment: Donde has puesto `tamaño` ¿no sería `longitud` ? Y aunque esto es pseudocódigo y no código, yo creo que queda más claro si la longitud la expresas como `tamaño(numeros)/tamaño(numeros[0])`

Comment: tambien te podrias ahorrar la asignación en numeroActual remplazando la sumatoria como sumatoria = sumatoria + numeros[i] o más simple sumatoria += numeros[i], ademas de lo que dijo @abulafia cambia lo de tamaño por longitud;

Comment: Chavo, lo de pseudocódigo en C sera algo especial de tu lugar de estudios. Tendras que consultarlo con tu profesor

Comment: Muchas gracias por los consejos.